# Create a layout like "1-day" view of google calendar application

Tags: android, calendar, timeline

I would like to create a layout like this.

[image]

I don't know how add the events to the timeline. I've done my timeline with a ListView. The events can be of 1h, 1,5h, 2h, 2.5h, .... and I don't know which kind of view, and how add to the timeline.

Any idea or example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google I|O conference application](https://github.com/google/iosched) has a similar UI, which you can try reusing.

Comment: content can't available at your link

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing, and could find no good options, so I created the [yadview](https://code.google.com/p/yadview/) project (https://code.google.com/p/yadview). yadview is a fork of the DayView schedule in the AOSP Calendar app, but has been reworked significantly to allow for integration into your application.

Here's a sample screenshot:
[image: yadview screenshot]